# Информация об ОС пользователя

Tags: php

Можно ли через php узнать подробную информацию об ОС пользователя (например, код продукта ОС), узнать характеристики процессора, видеокарты? Переменная `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` не даёт достаточной информации.

Comment: Видимо вопрос должен звучать как-то так:

*Есть ли возможность из php скрипта запросить у браузера информацию о конфигурации компьютера*

Что сводится к вопросу:

*Есть ли доступная JS функция браузера, возвращающая информацию о конфигурации компьютера*


Самому интересно. Подозреваю, что разработчики браузеров, руководствуясь соображениями безопасности, не предоставляют подобных интерфейсов.

Comment: ... и эта информация должна состоять из строки вида *"None of your business"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, этого сделать нельзя! Думаю, вы плоховато представляете, что такое веб-сервер, раз задаете подобные вопросы, но форумы для этого и нужны =) Сделать этого нельзя во-первых потому, что PHP код исполняется НЕ на компьютере юзера (кэп =) ), а на сервере, где лежит ваш сайт, а сервер обычно всего один, и находиться он может где-угодно...

Answer (score 0):

С помощью php  точно нет, а вот VBS может помочь.

Comment: Таким образом, Вы говорите, что клиентский VBS в IE может достать данные об ОС ?